# merging a large number vectors using move::semantic into a larger vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, c++14, move

I have a large number of objects that can be serialized into a `array<double, 5>`, let's call them `stuff`, I would like to merge all these objects into a large `vector<double>`, calling it `data`, to be used in messaging passing for synchronization between discrete local/remote nodes.

I thought using a move semantics for moving data for ***stuff*** into ***data*** should give me a huge performance boost over copying data, but in test, it actually performs considerably slower in debug mode, and in release mode slightly slower. I was thinking if there is a standard way of doing this for maximum performance? The followings are the implementions that I used:

```
std::vector<std::array<double, 5> > stuff(2000);
std::vector<double> data;
data.reserve(10000);
```

1)

```
for (auto & b : stuff) {
        data.insert(data.end(), std::make_move_iterator(b.begin()),
                std::make_move_iterator(b.end()));
}
```

2)

```
for (auto & b : stuff) {
    for (auto & item : b) {
        data.emplace_back(std::move(item));
    }
}
```

3)

```
for (auto & b : stuff) {
    std::move(b.begin(), b.end(), std::back_inserter(data));
}
```

4)

```
for (auto & b : stuff) {
    for (const auto & item : b) {
        data.emplace_back(item);
    }
}
```

P.S:
I am using g++ with the flags of `-O3 -march=native -mavx`

Comment: Type `double` (and `std::array` of `double`) doesn't benefit from `std::move` it always just copies. Maybe if your `std::array` were `std::vector` you might get some benefit.

Comment: The fastest would probably be `for (auto & b : stuff) data.insert(data.end(), b.begin(), b.end());`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, std::move can yield a performance boost, but it will only do so for complex types, that hold some kind of resources. Look at this example:

```
class MyVector {
    double* data;
    size_t size;

    ...

    MyVector(MyVector&& rhs) :
        data(rhs.data),
        size(rhs.size)
    {}

    MyVector(const MyVector& rhs) :
        data(new double[rhs.size]),
        size(rhs.size)
    {
        std::copy(rhs.data, rhs.data+size, data);
    }
    ...        
};
```

For our `MyVector` the move operation will be faster, because the allocation and the deep copy of the data can be circumvented and only an assigment is needed. We dont save any time for the size attribute, since it as to be assigned, just like in the copy constructor.
For types, that dont hold any ressources (like memory in the example), the move semantic will not improve performance. All the attributes have to be written to the new location and it doesn't matter, if we can delete the old object or not.

In your case you try to move `double` values, which have to be copied to the new location, no matter if you use move semantics or not. The reason, why you see a performance loss, is probably because you prevent the compiler from doing a single memcopy on the data. It is usually faster to do one memcopy operation, than the elementwise copies.

The fastes way to do your copy is most likely `std::memcpy`, followed by `std::copy`, which is specialised to use `std::memcpy` for trivial types. You might not see an improvement in speed, because the compiler recognised, that you want to copy a bulk of doubles and optimized your code to use memcpy anyway. If you want to find out what is happening, you can check the asm code using objdump or gdb.